# Issue with Advanced Query not returning desired results

Tags: mysql, outsystems

I have a table Projects which has the following fields

```
ID| Number  | Name    | CreatedOn  | CreatedBy 
----------------------------------------------
```

Other table is CLDProject has the following fields

```
ID| CLDId  | ProjectId | CreatedOn  | CreatedBy 
-----------------------------------------
```

Here I have to select the list of all Projects where the CLDProject.ProjectId is not assigned for the particular CLDId

I tried

```
SELECT {Project}.*
FROM {Project}
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM {CLDProjects} WHERE {CLDProjects}.[ProjectId] = {Project}.[Id] AND {CLDProjects}.[CLDId] =@CLDId)
```

[image]

The Problem is it shows all the Projects but I want to select projects where the CLDProject.ProjectId is not assigned for the particular CLDId. I am new to queries any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT {Project}.*
FROM {Project}
WHERE {Project}.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT {CLDProject}.[ProjectId]
    FROM {CLDProject}
    WHERE {CLDProject}.[CLDId] = @CLDId
    )
```

This is how it works

1. Find all projects associated with a given CLDID (inner query)
2. Find the projects that are not on that list (outer query)

Comment: Are you filling in the right \@CLDId parameter when calling the query in the flow? The way jff has it it looks like it should work...
If you're not passing the right \@CLDId the inner query will return no records, meaning the top query will not exclude any results and return you all {Project}s